# How to fix bad_typeid exception

Tags: c++, exception, recursion, try-catch, typeid

I was asked to create a simple program. See below:

"1. Write a simple program that uses recursion to compute the factorial of a number – make sure to throw an exception if the user enters a negative integer or a non integer data type from which to compute the factorial."

I have created the program to compute the factorial of a number into a while block, allowing the user to have unlimited attempts. My try-catch block works well for the negative exception, however, the non-integer exception is not working.

```
int Factorial(int input)
{
    if (input > 1)
        return input * Factorial(input - 1);
    else if (input < 0)
        throw NegativeException(input);
    else
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    int input;

    while (1)
    {
        try
        {
            cout << "Please enter an integer to find its factorial: ";
            cin >> input;
            cout << "The factorial of " << input << " is " << Factorial(input) << endl;
        }
        catch (const std::bad_typeid & ex)
        {
            cout << "Exception: " << ex.what();
            cout << "Try another integer\n" << endl;
        }
        catch (NegativeException& ex1)
        {
            cout << ex1.what();
            cout << "Try another integer\n" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I enter a letter, I expect the output to state "Exception: bad_typeid Try another integer". However, when I enter a letter instead of an int, the bad_typeid is not caught. It seems to return 0 and outputs "The factorial of 0 is 1". The while(1) block is then triggered and creates a never ending output of the above message.

I appreciate your time and assistance.

Comment: `cin >> input` will never throw a `std::bad_typeid`. Where did you read that it could ever throw that?

Comment: No where. I just assumed. I am (obviously) new to programming. I will make some changes to my code. Thank you for that information.

Comment: @Steve C++ is not like Python. Type mismatching is a compile-time error instead of a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

`bad_typeid` doesn't work like this. It is thrown when a `typeid` is applied to a dereferenced null pointer. Completely irrelevant in this case.

If, as an example, the user entered

```
5.5
```

then `std::cin >> input` would attempt to input an integer (5 in this case). If the user entered a letter like

```
foo
```

then `std::cin >> input` would set `failbit` and not throw an exception.